# Replacement drives for Equallogic PS6210X?

Tags: hard-drive, dell, dell-equallogic

**I'm searching for a replacement drive for a 1.2TB 10K 12Gb/s 2.5" hard drive that is showing multiple failures.**

A Dell representative has stated that p/n: 400-AHNG will work. I also see a very similar p/n: 400-AJPD available. However, neither show support for the Equallogic under their compatibility sections.

**Is there some special firmware required for Equallogic drives?**

And if so, part number would be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Equallogic storage arrays will only "accept" drives that are running Dell-branded firmware. Dell receives special-tailored firmware from hard drive vendors to "cooperate" more smoothly with their hardware, and some disk firmware versions are even specific to Equallogic arrays only (not used with other Dell hardware).

Assuming you're out of warranty, I would suggest searching for replacement parts by the P/N instead of the SKU. For that array model, JRPGV and TM6P6 look to be the only options to purchase from a third party.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, does it's in production ?

If **yes**, re-activate the hardware maintenance. For DELL a SAN in production must be in maintenance. As they will be able to update the drive firmware too if under maintenance. If DELL got stock those disks stock and you dont want to re-activate the maintenance I suggest you to stock some, as DELL keep the warranty/store stock separated. I will repeat my first statement, for a SAN in production for DELL it must be under maintenance.

If **no**: You can put any drive you want in the SAN. You might have to buy a full array of them on the other side as your array might don't want to use the drive alone. (I did it in a PS4100 for a lab, got 24 normal seagate SAS drive and the SAN seen them.)

**The why**:

An example I know: Their firmware allow the SAN to snapshot a disk that is near failling to another disk, to prevent a long recover time. So, you scrap the SAN resiliancy special feature by using non dell firmware.